# Ionic 3 Navigation menu issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm beginner to **IONIC** frame Work and I make some small project for my university ,I have some issue for header menu navigation, some pages are menu icon  not display,but I can touch and swap menu slider, how to show that menu Icon
**ion-header**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar><button ion-button [menuToggle]="activeMenu" right >
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
    <ion-title><p class="main-header">Add New Booking</p></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

please help me to fix it,
look my attached image you can understand it 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: i didn't get it actually,
when you go to the second page then you have not the menu icon in header, is that right?

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala  yes sir,i need to display menu icon,

Comment: Please check the accepted answer to the referenced question. The key is to add `persistent="true"` to the `ion-menu` element like this: `<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">`

Comment: @sebaferreras Thanks sir its work for me